# GNU parallel to keep docker-compose in attached mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run a bunch of docker-compose commands in parallel using GNU parallel. For some reason though, it looks like starting `parallel` force docker-compose in detached mode so I can't access the container output anymore.

I was hoping parallel would just keep docker-compose attached and print the output in order once the process is done.

Here's my command

```
echo 'tests/test_foo.py' | parallel -X docker-compose --project-name bar run --rm test py.test $*
```

Is there a way to force `docker-compose` to stay attached?

Comment: I do not know docker-compose, but it might depend on having a terminal. Can you try using `parallel --tmux`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no detached mode for `run`, it should always print the log lines to the terminal.  This seems to work for me with a single line of input.

However, calculating the container name is racy, so trying to run multiple instances like this may result in name conflict errors. You might need to use `--name` as an option to `run` to set a unique name for each.

You might also consider using [pytest-xdist](https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist) to run the tests in parallel inside a single `test` container.

Answer (score 1):

Further to [dnephin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947592/1318694), You can name each container with `parallel`'s positional arguments so there is no naming contention

```
echo -e "1\ttest1\n2\ttest2\n3\ttest3" | parallel -X --colsep '\t' docker-compose run --name proj{1} web echo {2}
```

In this demo the tab is used to separate the first field, used for the name and the second string used for the command.

You either need to use existing fields from `tests/test_foo.py` for the names or add this additional information if what you have in that file is not unique.